# Creating a unique session ID as a temporary username?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session-cookies

I am creating a web application in which I want non-registered users to be able to still use our service in a limited way during our launch just for usability purposes. In the future perhaps require registration.

Users will be able to post a lobby on the website and it will be associated with their username OR if they're not registered, some sort of session ID/cookie that persists 2 hours. If the user has created a lobby already, I would basically not want them to be able to create another one on the same connection.

Using CodeIgniter, how could I enforce this and use a unique session ID essentially as their username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate uniq id for user when they first land on the page, and then set cookie with given value (expiration time for 2h). Later on you can use this id during registration process.

Check out CodeIgniter [Cookie Helper](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/cookie_helper.html) and function [random_string](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/string_helper.html#random_string) to generate uniq id